# query_posts optimizing idea

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a taxonomy category `coupon_category` in a query_post I am trying to call all posr´ts from related custom taxonomy with the same `coupon_category`.

If I use:

```
<?php


                    // show all active coupons for this category from related store and setup pagination

                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', 
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => 'mode', 
                            ),
    )

                    ) );

                ?>
```

I can show all related posts with the term "mode" however I would like to automate so that always the terms (`coupon_category`) that are already in use on the page are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution

```
$tax = get_the_terms($id, 'coupon_category');
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                query_posts( array(
                    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'tax_query' => array( 
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug,
                        ),
)

                ) );
```